# I m trying to integrate ldap with devstack and when i did ./stack.sh i got this localrc: line 9: KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND: command not found

Tags: ldap, openstack, keystone

> localrc file
>  
>   ADMIN_PASSWORD=password2
>  MYSQL_PASSWORD=password2
>   RABBIT_PASSWORD=password2
>  SERVICE_PASSWORD=password2
>   SERVICE_TOKEN=token2
>   
>  ENABLED_SERVICES=key,n-api,n-crt,n-obj,n-cpu,n-net,n-cond,cinder,c-sch,c-api,c-vol,n-sch,n-novnc,n-xvnc,n-cauth,horizon,mysql,rabbit,ldap
>   
>  KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND=ldap
>   
>  KEYSTONE_CLEAR_LDAP=yes 
>  LDAP_PASSWORD=9632

I followed this website(http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-ldap-keystone/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming the above snippet is from a file written in shell script. Your example looks Ok.

I checked the link you provided and noted that the line you say failed is written in the IBM example as:

```
KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND = ldap
```

Which is not legal sh (or bash) and would cause the error message you described.

```
KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND = ldap
-bash: KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND: command not found
```

I suspect you copied and pasted the bad example from the link into your localrc file, which caused the error you saw, but somehow when you wrote the SO question, you corrected the mistake by removing the spaces around the "=".

### Edit: Investigation

#### ;TLDR

Create a file in the root of the **devstack** repo, *devstack/local.conf* with the contents:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=password2
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password2
RABBIT_PASSWORD=password2
SERVICE_PASSWORD=password2
SERVICE_TOKEN=token2 
ENABLED_SERVICES=key,n-api,n-crt,n-obj,n-cpu,n-net,n-cond,cinder,c-sch,c-api,c-vol,n-sch,n-novnc,n-xvnc,n-cauth,horizon,mysql,rabbit,ldap 
KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND=ldap 
KEYSTONE_CLEAR_LDAP=yes 
LDAP_PASSWORD=9632
```

#### Full Description

I installed devstack on Centos7 (using the [Devstack Quick Start Guide](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/devstack/?cm_mc_uid=10608627154414618027269&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1468776436)):

```
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
cd devstack
./stack.sh
```

I entered passwords as prompted, but eventually it failed with the error:

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

I traced the problem to a limited PATH in the sudoers entry, and because my postgreSQL install is in a non-standard location, I linked **pg_config** into */usr/local/bin* and ran stack.sh again:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config /usr/local/bin/pg_config
./stack.sh
```

(You probably won't have to do this if Postgres is in a standard location).

Install took a long time -

```
This is your host IP address: 192.168.200.181
This is your host IPv6 address: ::1
Horizon is now available at http://192.168.200.181/dashboard
Keystone is serving at http://192.168.200.181/identity/
The default users are: admin and demo
The password: 12345678
2016-07-17 18:16:32.834 | WARNING: 
2016-07-17 18:16:32.834 | Using lib/neutron-legacy is deprecated, and it will be removed in the future
2016-07-17 18:16:32.834 | stack.sh completed in 1447 seconds.
```

I killed the devstack session and did it all again with a clean git repo and with a localrc file.

```
./unstack.sh
cd ..
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack
cd devstack
cat << __EOF > local.conf
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=password2
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password2
RABBIT_PASSWORD=password2
SERVICE_PASSWORD=password2
SERVICE_TOKEN=token2 
ENABLED_SERVICES=key,n-api,n-crt,n-obj,n-cpu,n-net,n-cond,cinder,c-sch,c-api,c-vol,n-sch,n-novnc,n-xvnc,n-cauth,horizon,mysql,rabbit,ldap 
KEYSTONE_IDENTITY_BACKEND=ldap 
KEYSTONE_CLEAR_LDAP=yes 
LDAP_PASSWORD=9632
__EOF
./stack.sh
```

This time there were no password prompts, so the local config was definitely read.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in the localrc filealso i did the same thing (no spaces) but still error,but if replace the ENABLED_SERVICES with enable_service ldap its working but i cant log in to dash board

Comment: What is reading the contents of the file "localrc"? If it is another script, what shell is that script using? I am assuming bash.

Comment: I think so but i m not sure of it

Comment: what i did was also same but i cloned the devstack/liberty and in ubuntu and the localrc (the above one only ) and everything runs fine no errors in terminals but i cant log in to dash board